# Fetch and save in a variable

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, fetch-api

I am accessing a sheet from which I extract data to put it into a script object globally so I can use it in the rest of the code, however I am not getting the data out of the fetch function even though I am saving it inside the object.

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const spreadsheet = '...'

var data = {
    welcome: '',
    q1: '',
}

fetch(sheet)
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(text => {
        const json = JSON.parse(text.substr(47).slice(0, -2))
        data.welcome = json.table.cols[0];    
    })

    
console.log(data.welcome)
```

I got this error:

```
ReferenceError: json is not defined
    at file:///Users/getFAQSheet.js:32:13
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:197:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:337:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:88:5)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:61:12)
```

Comment: unclear how that code would throw that error.

Comment: Move the `console.log()` inside the last `.then()`

Comment: [And then there's this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @Andy Close it as dup?

Comment: @Andy this doesn't explain why `json` would be `undefined` in the code provided

Comment: @KonradLinkowski, I never said it would.

Comment: @TheMaster It works that way but then I don't have the data in my object